# Trying to get "website" validated through W3 Validator

Tags: html, css, validation

I am using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). It keeps telling me I have numerous errors in regards to each of my span tags.

example of error:

```
Line 21, Column 117: Attribute span not allowed on element span at this point.
<span id="answer1" span style="color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:block;margin:-18px auto;"></span><br/>
```

How would I fix this?

One of my thoughts was to try and put the information of the span into an external CSS document, would that idea work? If not what would be a better way to do it?

Comment: Sorry the span line didn't follow the example <span id="answer1" span style="color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:block;margin:-18px auto;"></span><br/>

Comment: Just a typo error. `<span id="answer1" span `

Comment: I am very thankful for everyone's input on this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already defined the span tag.

```
<span id="answer1"</span>
```

Try this instead:

```
<span id="answer1" style="color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:block;margin:-18px auto;"></span><br/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the word `span` as an attribute in your span tag:

```
<span id="answer1" span style="color:lightgreen;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;display:block;margin:-18px auto;"></span><br/>
                   ^^^^
```

which is invalid.

Also note that it's often recommended to avoid inline styling of elements and to use a stylesheet instead.

Comment: What would be the best way to put all of the elements into the stylesheet for the span id's?

Comment: thanks, I apologize to bother you, I have a total of 10 answer spans answer1-answer10, would it be possible to turn it into a class? or would you still recommend the id for the answers?

Comment: how would I go about doing that with a span?

Comment: You could just add a common class to all the spans. Like `<span id="answer1"  class="myclass"></span><span id="answer2"  class="myclass"></span>`. It's the same for any element.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that class option was very useful, and less tedious than copy and pasting #answer1 numerous times and editing